# auto-selection default branch when Merge Request

Tags: gitlab, merge-request

I would like to know if in Gitlab, it's possible to create rule when we push a merge request.

For example, for source branch : HF-458, I want that target branch was auto-selected on : hot_fixe_rct when I push my merge request.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use git alias to set something in your local so that every time you create MR, it takes the target branch in the alias.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/push_options.html#useful-git-aliases

Cheers!